# Invalid token after recording

Tags: joomla, visual-studio-2012, performance-testing

I am using visual studio to do web performance test i record the scenario using fiddler.I am testing a joomla website after i record a successful login when i run the test on visual studio the response is invalid token.Do someone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Joomla! login form contains a token that can only be used once.
You need to either load the actual login page from the server each time (so the server takes care of tokens) or - in a private testing environment - hack the core

```
components/com_users/controllers/user.php
```

at line 26/28 (Joomla 2.5 or 3) simply comment the first line of the login function:

```
public function login()
{
    //  JSession::checkToken('post') or jexit(JText::_('JInvalid_Token'));
```